# SwiftUI callback when (de)selecting an item

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following List:

```swift
List(selection: self.$selectionKeeper) {
    ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { name in
        Text(name)
    }
}
.environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
```

How can I get a callback each time an item is (de)selected? I know I can listen for changes in `selectionKeeper`, but I thought there might be a better way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way is to use `onChange` (or `onReceive` in iOS 13) to monitor changes to `selectionKeeper`:

```
List(selection: self.$selectionKeeper) {
    ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { item in
        Text("\(item)")
    }
}
.environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
.onChange(of: selectionKeeper) { selectedItems in
    print(selectedItems)
}
```

If you want to do it in another way, you can create a custom binding:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectionKeeper = Set<Int>()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: .init(
            get: {
                selectionKeeper
            },
            set: {
                selectionKeeper = $0
                selectionCallback($0)
            }
        )) {
            ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
    }
    
    func selectionCallback(_ selectedItems: Set<Int>) {
        print(selectedItems)
    }
}
```

You can also extract the binding as a computed property:

```
var listBinding: Binding<Set<Int>> {
    .init(
        get: {
            selectionKeeper
        },
        set: {
            selectionKeeper = $0
            selectionCallback($0)
        }
    )
}
```

```
List(selection: listBinding) { ... }
```

The `onChange` solution is simpler and more useful when you only need to react to changes to a specific variable. However, with a custom binding you get much more flexibility (you can change both `get` and `set`).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So there isn't any way to be notified when a specific cell is (de)selected, right? Other than listening to changes on the whole set

Comment: @Toma Yes, that's right. I'm not aware of any List initialisers that provide a callback for selection changes.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!